# Very difficult limit

Tags: calculus, limits

I am having trouble computing this limit:

$$\lim \limits_{x \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{\sin(\sin(\sin(x)))}{\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}\cos(x))}\cdot x^k$$

Comment: You should use a title that is more detailed. "Very difficult limit" isn´t informative. Additionally, what have you already tried ?

Comment: There is less to this than meets the eye.  The limit of $\frac{\sin(\sin(\sin x))}{x}$ is $1$. And the bottom behaves like $\frac{\pi x^ 2}{4}$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For expressions like these, it is often helpful to use Taylor series to simplify. For example, $$\sin\sin\sin x=x-x^{3}/2+O(x^{5}).$$
You should read about [Taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) if you are unfamiliar
with them. **I have omitted the series for $\cos(\frac{\pi}{2} \cos x)$ in case this is homework, giving you motivation to learn Taylor series**.

Once you plug the Taylor series into your expression, you should get the following (you can use this to check your work):
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\pi}{4}x^{k-1}=\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if }k>1;\\
\pi/4 & \text{if }k=1;\\
\text{DNE} & \text{if }k<1.
\end{cases}
$$